# Spark Structured Streaming - Log the internal progress of a query

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming, azure-monitoring

Let's assume the following setting: I have a stream of events. I want some specific events to trigger an action. Concrete case could be: stream of customers' orders and if the order meets certain set of conditions I want to send the customer a notification/SMS. At the same time, I want to track how fast I am processing the messages and monitor which order met which condition.

For notifications, I use Spark Structured Streaming code consisting of several operations:

```
df_orders = spark.readStream.format("eventhubs").options(**conf).load()

(df_orders
.filter(col('sms_consent') == True)
.filter(col('order_price') > 1000)
.dropDuplicates(['order_id', 'customer_id'])
.writeStream
.format('eventhubs')
.options(**conf)
.start()
)
```

Now I want to build a "monitoring/reporting" solution, which will export the following data for every incoming order:

```
+----------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+--------------------------+----------------------+
| order_id |  filtered_sms_consent |  filtered_order_price |  time_messageReceived |  time_processingFinished |  time_sentToEventHub |
+----------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+--------------------------+----------------------+
|        1 |  True                 |  None                 |  9:40:00              |  9:41:00                 |  None                |
|        2 |  False                |  False                |  9:41:00              |  9:42:00                 |  9:42:21             |
|        3 |  False                |  True                 |  9:43:00              |  9:45:00                 |  None                |
+----------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+--------------------------+----------------------+
```

*(The shape does not matter - the table can be de-pivoted to more "log-like" structure...)*

### My experiments:

**First**, I thought about using the **Spark listeners** (StreamingQueryListener) as it seems the Listeners are able to logs things such as the query state, average processing time etc.. But I couldn't find any solution to match certain event (order_id) with data from query listener.

**Next**, I wrote a **separate query** for monitoring while keeping the query for the actual logic execution. Issue is that since these are two separate queries, each is executed independently. Therefore, the timestamps are off. I managed to bound them together using the `foreachBatch()` [approach](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/structured-streaming/foreach.html#reuse-existing-batch-data-sources-with-foreachbatch). This however does encounter a problem with `dropDuplicates` (must split the query in two) and it feels very "heavy" (it is slowing down the execution quite a bit).

### Dream:

What I would love to have is something like:

```
(df_orders
.log('order_id {}: Processing started at {time}'.format(col('order_id'), time.now()) 
.filter(col('sms_consent') == True)
.log('order_id {}: filtered on sms_consent'.format(col('order_id'))
.filter(col('order_price' > 1000)
.log('order_id {}: filtered on sms_price'.format(col('order_id'))
...
)
```

or to have this information in spark logs by default and that have means to extract it.

How is this achievable?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can create UDF for sending logs to needed to you storage and call it during streaming and send data from each worker. It can be slow.
2. You can create UDF for logging to standard spark logs. And for look logs you need collect logs from all nodes. I used logstash for collect local logs from all nodes and kibana as dashboard.
3. If you need log time series data you can use spark metrics system https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#metrics and https://github.com/groupon/spark-metrics for custom metrics. This will allow to you
   create UDF and send custom metrics during streaming.